# Change DigitalOcean access token for docker-machine

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

I created a host using the DigitalOcean driver.  However, I had to generate a new access token and am now unable to connect to it.  How do I reconfigure docker-machine to use the new access token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each host spun up with `docker-machine` creates a folder holding its configuration under `~/.docker/machine/machines/` The DigitalOcean access token and other information about the droplet are stored in a `config.json` file. Let's look at a specific one as an example:

```
$ cat ~/.docker/machine/machines/docker-001/config.json | jq .
{
  "DriverName": "digitalocean",
  "Driver": {
    "AccessToken": "9dasd89ssf6542notarealtoken455b44sdgf4685",
    "DropletID": 4906043,
    "DropletName": "",
    "Image": "ubuntu-14-04-x64",
    "MachineName": "docker-001",
    "IPAddress": "45.32.128.70",
    "Region": "nyc3",
    "SSHKeyID": 7697371,
    "Size": "512mb",
    "CaCertPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
    "PrivateKeyPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
    "DriverKeyPath": "",
    "SwarmMaster": false,
    "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
    "SwarmDiscovery": ""
  },
  "CaCertPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
  "ServerCertPath": "",
  "ServerKeyPath": "",
  "PrivateKeyPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
  "ClientCertPath": "",
  "SwarmMaster": false,
  "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
  "SwarmDiscovery": ""
}
```